# Regex: Grab first instance of word unless "forbidden" word in between

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I need to match the first instance of either two words ("ham" or "turkey") ONLY if either word follows the word "sandwich" AND the word "forbidden" isn't present between "sandwich" and ("ham" or "turkey").

```
reuben sandwich with ham and turkey ham sandwich with cheese
reuben sandwich with forbidden ham and turkey ham sandwich with cheese
```

The regex I'm using is `sandwich(.*?)(?!.*forbidden)(ham)((.*?)(turkey))?` still matches the 2nd sentence.  How can I modify the regex to NOT match the 2nd sentence.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand your problem, but maybe https://regex101.com/r/gOs3ci/1 will help.

Comment: Or do you mean you need to match `ham` and then also `turkey` after it?

Comment: Thanks, I think this is exactly what I needed.  I do need to match the additonal ham or turkey at the end, but i added it myself sandwich((?:(?!forbidden).)*?)(ham|turkey)(.*?)(ham|turkey)

Comment: Just did some quick tests and this will work. If you want to add as an official answer I will accept it.  Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sandwich((?:(?!forbidden).)*?)(ham|turkey)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gOs3ci/1)

- `sandwich`   - matches a substring `sandwich`
- `((?:(?!forbidden).)*?)` - Group 1 matching any char that is not starting a `forbidden` word, zero or more times, as few as possible
- `(ham|turkey)` - either `ham` or `turkey`.

Here are some variations you may consider for your scenarios:

- If you need to match `ham` and/or `turkey` after `sandwich`, use [`sandwich((?:(?!forbidden).)*?)(ham|turkey)(.*?)(ham|turkey)`](https://regex101.com/r/oQcUfa/2)
- If you need to match only `ham` and then `turkey` or `turkey` and then `ham`, you can add a negative lookahead in the above regex: [`sandwich((?:(?!forbidden).)*?)(ham|turkey)(.*?)(?!\2)(ham|turkey)`](https://regex101.com/r/oQcUfa/1).